# Fire event when WPF button was pressed/unpressed

Tags: wpf, button

I need to fire some event when WPF button is pressed (by mouse, keyboard, touchscreen, etc) and to fire event when WPF buttons is unpressed.

How to do this? It should be easy but I can't find how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can derive from Button and override the [OnIsPressedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.onispressedchanged.aspx) method and fire a custom event there.

Or you can bind to the [ButtonBase.IsPressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed.aspx) property.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use DependencyPropertyDescriptor:

```
var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Button.IsPressedProperty, typeof(Button));
descriptor.AddValueChanged(this.button, new EventHandler(IsPressedChanged));
```

Comment: In fact, this solution discovered by the asker himself is the most perfect, bar none. It is not need inherit class, and only fires when "press" and "release" actually occur: press and release mouse main button and space. There will be no inability to handle space behavior due to the use of mouse events, nor will there be many unexpected scenarios from Enter key and Shortcut due to use `Click` event. And, with the simplest code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM, you can use event triggers to solve your problem. This way, you can still separate your UI requirements from your application logic.

- [Example 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Catel_Part5.aspx#SocialMediaEntry)
- [Example 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CinchV2_3.aspx#Interactivity)

Comment: I tried this way but you lose the Canexecute feature of commands.