# Is there an event that fires when an element becomes inactive

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF-MVVM application witch communicates with a plc. While a button is pressed a bool variable in the plc shoud stay `true` and if its released or lost focus or becomes inactive the variable should becomes `false` again.

I have the buttons implemented with events.
(Meanwhile there is an `PreviewTouchUp` and `PreviewTouchDown` event because there are multitouch screens.)

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="..."
    ...
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    ... >
    ...
    <Button>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CmdSetFlag}" CommandParameter="PlcVariable" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CmdResetFlag}" CommandParameter="PlcVariable" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <!-- followed by touch events -->
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

In my ViewModel are the commands `CmdSetFlag` and `CmdResetFlag`:

```cs
public MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MyViewModel(string pageName)
    {
        CmdResetFlag = new ActionCommand((p) => MyPlc.WriteVar(p.ToString(), false));
        CmdSetFlag = new ActionCommand((p) => MyPlc.WriteVar(p.ToString(), true));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Sets a bool on the plc to false.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand CmdResetFlag { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Sets a bool on the plc to true.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand CmdSetFlag { get; private set; }
}
```

So if the mouse or touch goes down the event fires and the commands called with the plc variable name as parameter.

Then there is a plc client class who writes to the plc itself:

```cs
/// <summary>
///   MyPlc is a static wrapper class.
///   It sends write and read commands to the actual plc implementation.
/// </summary>
public class MyPlc
{
    static MyPlc()
    {
        MyActualPlc = new ...Plc();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   The actual plc interface in use. There may any type of plc.
    /// </summary>
    private IPlc MyActualPlc { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Write a variable to the plc.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="varName">The name of the variable.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to write.</param>
    public void WriteVar(string varName, object value)
    {
        int myHandle = PlcClient.CreateVariableHandle(varName);
        PlcClient.WriteAny(myHandle, value);
        PlcClient.DeleteVariableHandle(myHandle);
    }
}
```

Is the mouse or touch released, the variable goes false again. So a value on the plc stays true until the button is released.

That works fine until there is an interruption like a window that opens on an event. Then neither the `PreviewMouseUp` nor the `PreviewTouchUp` event fires.

I also tried `LostFocus` without success.

Is there an event that can be used instead of `PreviewMouseUp` or `PreviewTouchUp`?

Comment: Wouldn't click do? That only executes when you actually released the mouse, or pressed enter. With touch I do not know though :)

Comment: The problem is, that some variable shoud stay true until the button is released. For example there is a pump that shoud run until the variable becomes false.

Comment: The Button has a property `IsPressed` which remains true as long as the button is pressed. You might try binding a boolean viewmodel property to the button's IsPressed property. But note that IsPressed goes to `false` if you continue to hold the mouse button held down, but temporarily move the pointer out of the button. It's not clear to me from your description if that's desired or not. Here's a quick XAML snippet to experiment with the behavior: `<Button x:Name="Button" Content="Press" /> <CheckBox Content="It's pressed" IsChecked="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=Button, Mode=OneWay}" />`

Comment: @EdPlunkett: `IsPressed` sounds nice but I can't add an event listener.

Comment: @AndyU. Show me the code and the error message. Explain what you’re trying to do. You lost me there.

Comment: I think the problem is solved with an `AttachedProperty`: In the `OnChange`Method I add the event (Mouse and Touch) using the propertie as "PlcVar". In addition there is add an `Behavior` to set the variable to `false` if the button becomes disabled or invisible. It seems to work but is still in test.

Comment: The problem is solved with a binding to a property. No events.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: A binding is problem, bacause the commands `CmdSetFlag`/`CmdResetFlag` are methods called with the parameter that is the name of the plc variable. The methods writes `true`/`false` to the this plc variable. In this way I want to get a sinal edge. In the ViewModel there is a property with the name of the plc variable (`PlcVar`) with only a setter: `private bool PlcVar => Plc.WriteVar(nameof(PlcVar), value);`. To set a variable: `PlcVar = true;` or reset with false. `IsPressed` _sends_ no change of the buttons status it only knows about it. So I used other events. See below.

Comment: @AndyU. The setter can execute any code it wants to. Maybe I misunderstand. In any case you have it working, which is good.

Comment: @EdPlunkett But `IsPressed="{Binding PlcVar}"` does not work. (`IsPressed="{Binding PlcVar, Mode=OneWayToSource}"` neither).

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What (in detail, much more detail than you think I need, seriously) behavior do you expect, and what do you see instead? (Again, please provide every detail you can possibly think of, especially the stuff that's too obvious to mention -- because it's not obvious to me what you're thinking).

Comment: I tried `<Button IsPressed="{Binding XAxisTippBackward}" Content="Back"/>` (can't work... error XDG0013 "IsPressed" has no Setter. But I think you mean `<Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=IsPressed}">` (used `Content` to see the result). So thats work! But now I need to change `Content` to a Property to bind to.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but what's a plc? I can find nothing in Google and I've never heard this acronym before.

Comment: @Clonkex - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245249/fire-event-when-wpf-button-was-pressed-unpressed) is the solution.

The problem is solved *for me* by using the events `IsEnabledChanged` (and `IsVisibleChanged`) added via behavior.

Maybe it only works because the buttons becomes disabled on opening an window that causes an interruption I descibed in my question.

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
    ...
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:NamespaceOfMyBehavior"
    ... >
    ...
        <Button...>
            <!-- The triggers looks like above -->
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>...</i:Interaction.Triggers>  
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ext:PlcButtonBehavior PlcVar="PlcVar"/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
        ...
</UserControl>
```

The Behavior class looks like

```cs
public class PlcButtonBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InvalidValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "InvalidValue", typeof(string), typeof(PlcButtonBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, (d, e) =>
                (PlcButtonBehavior)d).Update()));

    public string PlcVar
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(InvalidValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InvalidValueProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.IsEnabledChanged += AssociatedObject_IsEnabledChanged;
        AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged += IsVisibleChanged_IsVisibleChanged;
        Update();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.IsEnabledChanged -= AssociatedObject_IsEnabledChanged;
        AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged -= IsVisibleChanged_IsVisibleChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_IsEnabledChanged(
        object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Update();
    }

    private void IsVisibleChanged_IsVisibleChanged(
        object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Update();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject is Button button
            && button.IsVisible
            && button.IsEnabled
            && AssociatedObject.IsPressed)
        {
            Plc.SetFlag(PlcVar);           
        }
        else
        {
            Plc.ResetFlag(PlcVar);             
        }
    }
}
```

To set the events from the behavior as a trigger it does not work.

Answer (score -2):

"That works fine until there is an interruption like a window that opens on an event", im not sure do i understand that right, your events not working when your control (or app) lost focus?
Maybe you looking something like [Application.Deactivated Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.deactivated?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) - Occurs when an application stops being the foreground application.

Comment: I must also get event when the mouse got an other focus when a border becomes visible. There is a message border instead of a window. If there is a message, a variable is set an the border becomes via Binding visible. The border gets the focus but the `LostFocus` event of the button does not fire.